# Prove that if $g\in L^1(R)$, then $\lim_{\lambda\to\infty}||f_{\lambda}*g-g||_{L^1(R)}=0$, where $f_\lambda(x)=\frac{\lambda}{2}e^{-\lambda|x|}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

Prove that if $g\in L^1(R)$, then $\lim_{\lambda\to\infty}||f_{\lambda}*g-g||_{L^1(R)}=0$, where $f_\lambda(x)=\frac{\lambda}{2}e^{-\lambda|x|}$,
first of all it is worth noting that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_\lambda(x)dx=1$
$$g*f(x)-g(x)=\frac{\lambda}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty (g(x-y)-g(x))e^{-\lambda|y|}dy$$ how to proceed from here? I know it is worth splitting the interval into $[-\infty,\delta], [-\delta,\delta], [\delta,\infty]$ and use some theorem about approximating the function $L^1$ but I cant figure out how it works, any explanation appreciated.

Comment: You can choose $\delta$ small enough and $\lambda$ large enough that outside of $[-\delta, \delta], \int|f_\lambda| < \epsilon/\|g\|$. And inside $[-\delta,\delta]$, $\|g(x-y) - g(x)\|_{L^0} < \epsilon$.

Comment: But g is not continuous,  so why would this last inequality work?